# add throws declaration or surround with try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a very simple program which read a file. eclipse is asking me to either add throws declaration OR surround with try catch. which one is "proper". and why I have to have any of those if I already have try catch at method level?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filepath  = "xxxxx";
    readFile(filepath);


}
OR

 public static void main(String[] args)   {
    String filepath  = "xxxxx";
    try {
        readFile(filepath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private static void readFile(String path) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            //do something
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on specific case. There's no specific answer.

Comment: Let me ask this then. do I need IOException or IOException and try catch at the method level?

Comment: eclipse asks you to add try/catch or throws because your readFile method has a throws declaration. That means that the method that calls readFile has to either catch its IOException or declare it in the throws clause

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is usually the best:

Use `try/catch` if it's your program logic > the highest caller.

Use `throws` if it's a supplying method or a library > just one step of many.

In the case of a library you might also want to wrap a library specific exception around the one you get.

Best is to have a look at the Oracle docu page about Exceptions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason to re-throw over `try / catch` is that you want the `Exception` to bubble up the stack and deal with it from a calling method. You use a `try / catch` when you want to deal with the `Exception` there and then. For a simple example such as yours, a `try / catch` should suffice.

E.G. though, if you had a web application, you would want to handle that `Exception` gracefully and bubble it up the method calls in such a way that the user got a meaningful error message on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Which one is the proper one depends on your program. If you choose `throws` you'll have to handle the exception somewhere where the method is used (or let it bubble up to handle somewhere else).

If you choose to do it with a `try/catch` the method itself will handle the exception when something goes wrong.

The reason why you're getting the message is probably because you're not actually catching your exception at the method level. Since you only do `try/finally`

I would use the try/catch in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you decide to throws the exception you will have to take care of her at a higher level.

It is asking you to add this because this line outside the try/catch can throw a exception:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```